# Play framework with Scala 3

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, scala-3

I'm trying to update a Play Framework (2.8.8) project from Scala 2.13 to Scala 3 using [auto-migration plugin](https://scalacenter.github.io/scala-3-migration-guide/docs/tooling/scala-3-migrate-plugin.html).

Problem arises for dependencies that are not explicitly listed in `build.sbt` but rather (as far as I understand) resolved from `"com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.8"`

```
[info] com.typesafe.play:twirl-api:1.5.1 -> "com.typesafe.play" % "twirl-api_2.13" % "1.5.1"
[info] com.typesafe.play:play-docs:2.8.8:docs -> "com.typesafe.play" % "play-docs_2.13" % "2.8.8" % "docs"
[info] com.typesafe.play:play-logback:2.8.8  -> "com.typesafe.play" % "play-logback_2.13" % "2.8.8"
[info] com.typesafe.play:play-test:2.8.8:test -> "com.typesafe.play" % "play-test_2.13" % "2.8.8" % "test"
[info] com.typesafe.play:filters-helpers:2.8.8 -> "com.typesafe.play" % "filters-helpers_2.13" % "2.8.8"
[info] com.typesafe.play:play-server:2.8.8 -> "com.typesafe.play" % "play-server_2.13" % "2.8.8"
[info] com.typesafe.play:play-akka-http-server:2.8.8 -> "com.typesafe.play" % "play-akka-http-server_2.13" % "2.8.8"
```

It looks like `sbt-plugin` is only published for SBT 1.x and Scala 2.12 ([ie here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/)) but all listed incompatibilities (see above) already have `2.13` version which would be fine with Scala 3 `CrossVersion.for3Use2_13` flag.

Is there any way around it (overriding dependencies?) or am I stuck until `sbt-plugin` for 2.13 is released?

Comment: I don't think there's a way around this. Anyway, even if this would be possible theorically, some Play libraries rely on macros and wouldn't be compatible anyway with Scala 3. You should wait for an official release of Play Framework supporting Scala 3.

Comment: It's also worth noting that because sbt itself is exclusively 2.12, it's unlikely that there will ever be a 2.13 version of an sbt plugin; I'd expect sbt 2.0 to be Scala 3.  This doesn't directly preclude building projects in other versions of Scala with sbt.

Comment: @GaëlJ that's going to be a very long wait, minimum 6 months, and more likely a year before a Scala 3 supported version of Play lands. Lightbend no longer allocates significant developer resources (see [automated] commit activity) to the project, as was the case in the past.

If Play + Scala 3 lands in the near future it will be a community driven effort...

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing two separate issues: the Scala version used to build your sbt build, and the Scala version used to build your program. For the former you have to use Scala 2.12. For the latter, you can use whatever you want, including 3.0.0. The two don't have to match.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I'm indeed confusing the two. I'm even using 2.13.5 in build.sbt right now (so neither 3 nor 2.12). Do you maybe have some idea where I can learn more about it?

Answer (score 1):

Play Framework does not support Scala 3, as of August 2021. Play depends on lots of other libraries, not all of them support Scala 3 yet.

So even if you configure sbt correctly, as per Matthias' answer, apparently you still cannot use Scala 3 yet.

Here's a discussion thread over at the Play Framework forum, about Scala 3:

https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/scala-3-0-support/7729/10

> [...] It’s not as easy as simply making Play itself work with Scala 3. Play depends on various other projects and libraries

Answer (score 1):

I have something like this included in my `build.sbt` so that I can build my project with `3.0` and still depend on libraries only available using `2.13`

```scala
val scala3Version = "3.0.2"

val libVersion = "0.0.1"

lazy val projectName = project
    .in(file("exampleproject"))
    .settings(
        ...,
        libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
            ...,
            "com.example.lib" %% "lib-name" % libVersion,
        ).map(_.cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13))
    )
```

Their documentation has changed a lot, but is relatively stable now: [Scala 3 Migration Guide Doc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/tutorial-sbt.html#:%7E:text=2.%20There%20is%20no%20Scala%203%20version%20of%20the%20library)